# Can I initialize variable in bash using scientific notation?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to initialize variable in bash using scientific notation like in python or other programming languages.

a=1e5

I know in bash there is no variable type while initializing. Hence the above line if printed

echo $a

produces an output like

1e5

I want the value of a to be 100000

Comment: In bash, all variables are of type string (respectively array of strings). You can treat that look like integers as if they were integers. You don't have builtin support for floats.

Comment: Assuming you just want better readability for large numbers, executing (built-in) commands like `printf` might be a bit overkill or even miss the objective completely. In such cases, I often abuse empty quotes for grouping. E.g. `a=5000000` (= 1e6) can be written as `a=5''000''000`. The result is exactly the same, because bash will remove the empty quotes before assigning the string to `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s *builtin* **`printf  [-v varname]`**, (without any fork to `bc`, `awk`, `perl` or any else)!

#### shortly:

Strictly answering you question: Instead of

```
a=1e5
```

write:

```
printf -v a %.f 1e5
```

## From scientific to number (float or integer)

```
printf '%.0f\n' 3e5
300000
```

`%f` is intented to produce *floating* numbers. `%.0f` mean `0` fractional digits. Note that `0` could be *implicit*: **`%.f`** !

```
printf '%.f\n' 3e5
300000

printf  '%.2f\n' 1234567890e-8
12.35
```

#### Assingning answer to/from a variable:

```
myvar=1.25e6
printf -v myvar %.f "$myvar"
echo $myvar
1250000
```

## From number to scientific

```
printf '%.10e\n'  {749999998..750000000}
7.4999999800e+08
7.4999999900e+08
7.5000000000e+08
```

#### Assingning answer to/from a variable:

```
myvar=314159.26
printf -v myvar %e "$myvar"
echo $myvar
3.141593e+05
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash` does not support scientific notation or floats, in your case you can use `awk`

```
awk -v v=1e5 'BEGIN {printf("%.0f\n", v)}'
```

printing

```
100000
```

Comment: You assertion is wrong: `bash`'s builtin `printf` work well with scientific notation!